# Discard all changes in Github Desktop (Mac)

Tags: github, github-for-mac

How to discard all changes in Github desktop (mac), comparing to the latest commit?

It is possible to click on one file and select "discard changes". But how to discard all changes in files?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested, it can be done via GitHub's Menu Bar: Repository/Discard changes to selected files.

Comment: I don't see this on Github Desktop version 1.0.10 (Windows), but Jonathan's answer worked for me. Right click on 'N changed files' at the top of the changed files list, and you'll find the option to 'Discard All Changes'

Comment: @Andrew As tag says, its for Mac version.

Comment: It doesn't work already. Now you need to right click on `changed files`. As Jonathan said below.

Answer (score 11):

Right click on any file and you'll find the option to 'Discard All Changes':

[image]

Comment: This is the actual answer, they've updated it recently.

Comment: This is the only way to do it in the new version I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone would be interested to do this without Github Desktop, since I got to this page by searching;

> "How discard all changes work in Github Desktop?"

Just run the command below in your project folder from terminal:

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: In 2022 I would use `git restore` which is commit history immutable, rather than `git reset --hard` that would be commit history mutable : any mutable operations are not recommended, especially for beginners who understand very little on how Git works !

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
git checkout .
```

to revert local changes and add a

```
git pull
```

to fetch the latest code from remote

Comment: You should add, that you are referencing the GitHub desktop client.