# Is there a way to discard only one single change in GitHub Desktop?

Tags: github-desktop

I am new at using GitHub Desktop, so far, great tool. Do what it needs to do.

But now, I've made a few changes to one file and am looking for an opportunity to only discard one single change, not all changes, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47643254/2438518).

Isn't there a way to do so?
That would mean for me, that I have to switch to another git gui client.

Answer (score 0):

They cover this subject in this [documentation link](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/making-changes-in-a-branch/committing-and-reviewing-changes-to-your-project#discarding-changes-in-one-or-more-lines).

If this does not satisfy your case, you may give a try to [Fork](https://git-fork.com/). This is my tool of choice and it allows that kind of operations very straightforward and easily.